# How to use pipes in C?

Tags: pipe

I tried to write a code where a variable should be updated in shared memory. So, I used fork() to create child process. The problem that I have is that I don't know how to use pipes, so that when some value has been reached and one process determines that, it should tell the other process that the output is finished, by using pipe. I was looking at lot of examples where pipes have been used, but still I am not sure how to implement that. If anyone could help me with some guidelines how to do this, I would be really thankful. 
Here is the code:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <semaphore.h>
 #include <sys/mman.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>

    int main(void)
{
int * shared=mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
 printf("Value of the variable at the beginning: %d\n", * shared);
pid_t pid;
pid=fork();

if(pid==0)
{
int a=0;
a=* shared;
a+=3;
 printf("Child process: %d\n", a);
sleep(rand()%10);
}
   else{
 int b=0;
b= * shared;
b+=2;  
 printf("Parent process: %d\n", b);
sleep(rand()%10);
     } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the input of a child process to output of your parent process.
Keep in mind that example below redirects standard output of the parent to the standard input of the child... if you want parent to still be able to print to the console drop the second `dup` and `close` calls and use just used pipefd[0] as a file handle

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int pipefd[2];
  int pid;

  int * shared=mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  pipe(pipefd);

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    {

      dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
      close(pipefd[1]);

      int a=0;
      a=* shared;
      a+=3;
      printf("Child process: %d\n", a);
      sleep(rand()%10);

      // Here you can read from stdin and to get input from parent process 
   }
  else
    {
       int b=0;
       b= * shared;
       b+=2;  
       printf("Parent process: %d\n", b);

       dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
       // At this point you won't be able to output from parent to the console
       // your output will not go to the child
       close(pipefd[0]);
       sleep(rand()%10);          
    }
}
```